# How to add new column in SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy which is not present in Excel using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, sqlbulkcopy

I am creating an application which will upload data from Excel to SQL Server using ASP.NET. I know how to upload Excel data using `SqlBulkCopy`. But I am trying to upload some extra data for the table column (`addeddate`, `addedby`...etc) which is not present in the Excel sheet.

I get this error:

> The given ColumnName '18-01-2016 17:24:07' does not match up with any column in data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution to insert constant values like addeddate, addedby...etc.

```
SELECT
    EXCEL_COL1, 
    EXCEL_COL2, 
    'newconstantvalue' as CustomCol 
FROM
    ExcelSheet1

Then

bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Table_COL3", "CustomCol");
```

Please refer the [article](http://dotnetmentors.com/c-sharp/bulk-upload-into-sql-server-using-sqlbulkcopy-and-c-sharp.aspx) for more detail.